# Graphical Timer control not working correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, controls

This is a custom control I have made, a graphical timer, however, it is not working correctly. As the time left decreases a pie is filled to represent the amount of time left decreasing, but it is decreasing with unexpected angles (which are output to the listbox for debugging purposes). How do I get it to work correctly? Also I'm very new to making Custom Controls (this is my first) so any pointers on good coding guidelines, what not to do, etc, would be very helpful.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestCustomControl
{
    class GraphicalTimer : Control
    {
        public Color Timer { get; set; }
        public Color TimerEmpty { get; set; }
        public Color BorderColor { get; set; }
        private Timer t;
        public int MaxTime { get; set; }
        private int timeElapsed = 0;
        public GraphicalTimer()
        {
            DoubleBuffered = true;

            SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
            BackColor = Color.Transparent;

            t = new Timer();
            t.Interval = 1000;
            t.Tick += t_Tick;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            t.Start();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            t.Stop();
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            timeElapsed = 0;
            Invalidate();
        }

        void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timeElapsed += 1;
            if (timeElapsed == MaxTime)
            {
                t.Dispose();
            }
            Invalidate();
        }

        private float getAngleFromTime()
        {
            if (timeElapsed == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                MainWindow.lb.Items.Add((360 / (MaxTime / timeElapsed)).ToString());
                return (360 / (MaxTime / timeElapsed));
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            Rectangle rc = ClientRectangle;

            g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Timer), rc);
            g.FillPie(new SolidBrush(TimerEmpty), rc, -90, getAngleFromTime());
            g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(BorderColor, 4), rc);

            Font font = new Font("Arial", (float)rc.Height * 0.4f, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
            sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            g.DrawString((MaxTime - timeElapsed).ToString("D2"), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new RectangleF((rc.Width - rc.Width / 2) / 2, (rc.Height - rc.Height / 2) / 2, rc.Width * 0.7f, rc.Height * 0.7f));
        }
    }

    class MainWindow : Form
    {
        GraphicalTimer gt;
        Button startButton;
        Button stopButton;
        Button resetButton;
        public static ListBox lb;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.Text = "Test Application";
            gt = new GraphicalTimer();
            gt.MaxTime = 20;
            gt.BorderColor = Color.BurlyWood;
            gt.Timer = Color.Aqua;
            gt.TimerEmpty = Color.White;
            gt.Top = 10;
            gt.Left = 10;
            gt.Width = 50;
            gt.Height = 50;
            this.Controls.Add(gt);

            startButton = new Button();
            startButton.Top = 70;
            startButton.Left = 30;
            startButton.AutoSize = true;
            startButton.Text = "Start Timer";
            startButton.Click += startButton_Click;
            this.Controls.Add(startButton);

            stopButton = new Button();
            stopButton.Top = 70;
            stopButton.Left = startButton.Right + 10;
            stopButton.AutoSize = true;
            stopButton.Text = "Stop Timer";
            stopButton.Click += stopButton_Click;
            this.Controls.Add(stopButton);

            resetButton = new Button();
            resetButton.Top = 70;
            resetButton.Left = stopButton.Right + 10;
            resetButton.AutoSize = true;
            resetButton.Text = "Reset Timer";
            resetButton.Click += resetButton_Click;
            this.Controls.Add(resetButton);

            lb = new ListBox();
            lb.Top = resetButton.Bottom + 10;
            lb.Left = 10;
            lb.Width = this.ClientSize.Width - 20;
            lb.Height = this.ClientSize.Height - lb.Top - 10;
            this.Controls.Add(lb);
        }

        void resetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gt.Reset();
        }

        void stopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gt.Stop();
        }

        void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gt.Start();
        }
    }

    class StartClass
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            MainWindow form = new MainWindow();
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I won't debug the entire program, but you are using integers to calculate the angle, and in a way that can cause quite some jitters. Try using floating point numbers for the calculation and then converting the final result into an integer value if you need it that way. Even writing `360 * timeElapsed / MaxTime` might reduce the artifacts.

Comment: @Dirk thanks, you're a life saver xD. I changed `return (360 / (MaxTime / timeElapsed));` to `return ((float)360 / ((float)MaxTime / (float)timeElapsed));` which fixed it, then ended up changing it to `360 * timeElapsed / MaxTime` cause it looks nicer

Comment: @Dirk If you put it as an answer I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using integers to calculate the angle, and in a way that can cause quite some jitters.

`360 / (MaxTime / timeElapsed)` will first evaluate `temp = MaxTime / timeElapsed` in integer arithmetics, and then `360 / temp` also using integer division.

Try using floating point numbers for the calculation and then converting the final result into an integer value if you need it that way. Even writing `360 * timeElapsed / MaxTime` might reduce the artifacts as you then first multiply `360 * timeElapsed` which is accurate (unless timeElapsed is very large).

Answer (score 0):

The method of calculating  AngleForTime is wrong. Just replace your method with below code and it should do your job.

;)

```
private float getAngleFromTime()
        {
            if (timeElapsed == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                MainWindow.lb.Items.Add((360*timeElapsed) / MaxTime ).ToString();
                return (360*timeElapsed) / MaxTime ;
            }
        }
```